# WebScraping Selenium vs HtmlUnit

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, htmlunit

I have simple project for self-learning in java. One module from this project have to scrap a list of films from a cinemas.

Its not any problem if a cinema website is not full of javascript,
        I can just use Jsoup.
    There is example [CinemaCityShowtimes](https://www.cinema-city.pl/kina/bielsko-biala#/buy-tickets-by-cinema?in-cinema=1088&at=2018-02-12&view-mode=list) where list is loaded from server (with ajax, yes?),
        so i thought that i can use HtmlUnit.

Problem: HtmlUnit (and Postman too btw) dont see this page in the same way as browser.
    I tried a lot of suggestions from stackoverflow and official HtmlUnit page,
        like waiting for javascript starting before or try to set Ajax Controller,
        but nothing.
    With Selenium is no problem, example code:

```
final WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(CINEMA_URL);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".light")));
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.movie-row"));
```

But its clear that i dont want to use Selenium when i can use HtmlUnit (and i know that i cant use Jsoup here),
        so i searching for solution in HtmlUnit.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or had same problem?

EDIT: one of my samples in HtmlUnit:

```
private static final String URL_CINEMA = "https://www.cinema-city.pl/kina/arkadia#/buy-tickets-by-cinema?in-cinema=1074&at=2018-02-14&view-mode=list";

private static WebClient config(){
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            return webClient;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebClient webClient = config();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL_CINEMA);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(3000);
        String content = page.asXml();
        System.out.println(content); // save(content)
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to use _HtmlUnit_ without _Selenium_ ? Can you show us your code trials with `tried a lot of suggestions from stackoverflow and official HtmlUnit page, like waiting for javascript starting before or try to set Ajax Controller` ?

Comment: First, thank you for answer.
Yes, i want to use only HtmlUnit.

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(30000);
        return webClient;

Comment: I am afraid, you have tagged `selenium` and _Selenium_ through it's _Java_ clients can use _HtmlUnit_ to execute the _Testcases_. But I am not sure without _Selenium_ if that can be possible.

Comment: Sorry, but the code you have posted can't be the complete one. There is no retrieval of any page. Please post a complete sample. And webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore is NOT an option. You have to call this after some retrieval/action.

Comment: You are absolutely right RBRi, and good point with waitingForBackgroundJs. I edit my main post and put there a one of samples.